# join 2 column containing date and time info into datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 column  containing

```
DATE (Varchar),Time (Varchar)
=============================
20121231, 172109
-----------------
20130502, 163107
-----------------
20130502, 163148
------------------
20130502, 163206
------------------
20130502, 163207
-------------------
```

I want to Combine into 1 datetime column
Expected Result should be.

```
2012-12-31 17:21:09
------------------
2013-05-02 16:31:07
------------------
2013-05-02 16:31:48
------------------
2013-05-02 16:32:06
------------------
2013-05-02 16:32:07
------------------
```

Can anybody share the query pl.?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: SQL is a language implemented to a greater or lesser extent by various different products. Date/time handling is an area with a large amount of variation in language features and support, so we need to know what product you're working with. Please add a suitable tag for your RDBMS product.

Comment: I am using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

give this a try,

This will output a value with a datatype is `DATETIME`

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF([date],5,0,'-'), 8,0, '-') + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF([time],3,0,':'),6,0,':'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5951a/13)

This will output a `STRING`

```
STUFF(STUFF([date],5,0,'-'), 8,0, '-') + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF([time],3,0,':'),6,0,':')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5951a/14)

*follow-up question, why are you saving date/time as varchar in different columns in the first place?*

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING ( date ,0 , 5 )+
              '-'+
              SUBSTRING ( date ,5 , 2 )+
              '-'+
              SUBSTRING ( date ,7 , 2 )+
              ' '+
              SUBSTRING ( time ,0 , 3 )+
              ':'+
              SUBSTRING ( time ,3 , 2 )+
              ':'+
              SUBSTRING ( time ,5 , 2 )
               as datetime
              from datetime;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/711c4/13)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7461/7)

```
select convert(datetime,LEFT([DATE],4)
                        +'-'+
                        SUBSTRING([DATE],5,2)+
                        +'-'+
                        RIGHT([DATE],2)+
                        ' '+
                        LEFT([TIME],2)
                        +':'+
                        SUBSTRING([TIME],3,2)+
                        +':'+
                        RIGHT([TIME],2)
                        ,120)
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),
    CONVERT(DATETIME,TM.DateValue),120 ),' 00:00:00',' ')
    +STUFF(STUFF(TM.TimeValue, 3,0,':'),6,0,':')
    FROM TableName TM
```